# To apprixmate a multivariate function with a neural network, which activation function to use?

Tags: deep-learning

I would like to approximate a multi-variate function that looks like this:

[image]

I was thinking of using the Sigmoid function to keep a continuous output, but I am wondering if there exist a better choice.

Thanks

Comment: I wouldn't opt for sigmoid. Just keep the last layer linear, as it is not bounded, and has no vanishing gradients.

Comment: @Gulzar thank you, do you mean that I should not use a transfer function for the last layer ?

Comment: @Gulzar What about the transfer function for the other hidden layers ?

Comment: You can just use all Linear layers, with leaky-relu activation. This is the most standard and straight forward, and go from there.

Comment: and yes, no activation on the last layer.

Comment: Ok thank you, I would like to be able to justify my choice also :)

Comment: In deep learning, if it works, it works. Start simple, and build from there. No need to complicate things